# ServiceStack selfhosted performance on Raspberry

Tags: servicestack

I have a C# console application with a self hosted ServiceStack server (based on AppSelfHostBase).
It has both REST API (get and post) and a "standard" html/javascript website.

If i run the code under Windows, it works great, but if i run using RaspberryPI, it is slow and never got a response.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Leonardo Zambonelli

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ServiceStack on Mono on Raspberry PI I'd recommend [converting your project to .NET Core](http://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v4.5.2) which will provide an instant performance improvement.

All .NET Core Apps are Console Apps and you can checkout the [ServiceStack .NET Core Apps](https://github.com/NetCoreApps/) for examples of ServiceStack Apps running on .NET Core.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks mythz!
I'm not worried about performance at the moment, but the main problem is that is not working at all! I don't need high performance because it's just a Rest Service that is used by one user(app) at a time.

The application is quite big, and converting to .net seems to be quite hard (we use a lot of serial port communication, and other stuff that are not present in .net core)

Added: just a quick note. On a Virtual Linux machine it works fine, so the problem seems to be only on Mono on Raspberry. If someone has any suggestion ( a part converting the project) it would be useful.

Thanks
Leo